# MVC4 - EF Error String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been going crazy with this error for a couple of days now and no attempts to solve it seem to be working.  I've searched on this error and everything I see says to check the size of the DB columns, which I've done and have even set them to varchar(MAX).  Here's the strange part, it works when I test locally using VS2012, but when I deploy to my web server and test I see the above error.

I even tried this against an out of the box templated MVC4 web app and the same thing happens, it works fine when I test locally, but as soon as I deploy to the server I get the above error when I try and insert or edit. I do have triggers on the table, but since insert and edit works fine when I'm running locally, I don't believe that is the issue.

Anyone have any thoughts?  This is really driving me crazy!

TIA!

Comment: Can you show us your data model, the table and the data you are trying to insert?

Comment: Do you still get an error when deployed to your server if you disable your triggers?  It would be useful to rule out the triggers completely, so we know the insert/edit from the MVC app is definitely the culprit

Comment: Did you check the SQL query that causes the error? Also pay attention to variable declarations. EF may declare too narrow variables for query parameters.